# setting up select2 form with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-select2

I'd like to insert the function select2TemplateResult as attribute 'templateResult' for a select2 form. I don't understand how the attribute 'templateResult' can be set as a custom function which I've defined in a .js file which is called before than creating the select2 component.

lib.js

```
function select2TemplateResult(data, container) {
    console.log('aaa');
    if (data.element) {
        $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("status"));
        console.log($(data.element).attr("status"));
    }
    return data.text;
}
```

form.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib.js"></script>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('elements') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label>Example</label>
    <select name="elements[]" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" templateResult=select2TemplateResult() data-placeholder="Select an element" style="width: 100%;">
        <?php
        $key_name = "name";
        $key_status = "status";
        foreach ($elementSource->getElements() as $v){
            echo "<option selected='selected' status=$v[$key_status]>$v[$key_name]</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

The php code is inside a laravel .blade.php file, and I need to add a class to the select2 pills (both selections and options, but let's just deal with the templateResult function for a sake of simplicity) in order to modify their appearance with a .css file. I know that by creating the select2 element with javascript this would be easy, but I'd like to keep creating the select2 form with the php code, if possible, in order to keep the code clean, also because I don't need always the templateResult function (there are many other cases in my pages).

There are probably many errors in this code... Please give me some hints!
Thanks

Comment: whats the problem, you can call it, after loading select2.

Comment: do you mean putting the <script> lines after the select2 declaration? it doesn't work anyway, no class is added and no console.log is printed anyway

Comment: Tell me scenario, I means purpose, I can help you guide on that. This is however messy to do and understand obv.

Comment: I've added a clarification in the question :)